# Android Exit sub nav graph

Tags: android, kotlin, android-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I am using one nav_graph and I have a scenario like I have fragment1 and going to other fragment which is a sub nav graph and it has a couple of
fragments(fragment3 and fragment4) and start destination is fragment3 and from fragment3 I am going to fragment4 and fragment4 has "DONE" button.

Here is the scenario:

1. I am calling this sub nav graph from fragment1 and from fragment4 I want to redirect to it is parent i.e fragment1
2. I am calling this sub nav graph from fragment2 and from fragment4 I want to redirect to it is parent i.e fragment2

This is how I am handling the done button click event inside fragment4:

```
findNavController().currentDestination?.parent?.startDestination?.let {
            findNavController().popBackStack(it, true)
        }
```

But it is not redirecting to parent it is redirecting to the subgraph stat destination i.e fragment3

Here is how my nav_graph is looking:

Here are two fragments:

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:name="fragment1"
        android:label="fragment1">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_fragment1_to_sub_graph"
            app:destination="@id/sub_graph_id" />
</fragment>

<fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"
        android:name="fragment2"
        android:label="fragment2">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_fragment2_to_sub_graph"
            app:destination="@id/sub_graph_id" />
</fragment>
```

Here is my sub nav graph:

```
<navigation
        android:id="@+id/sub_graph_id"
        app:startDestination="@id/fragment3">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment3"
            android:name="fragment3"
            android:label="fragment3">
            
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_fragment3_to_fragment4"
                app:destination="@id/fragment4" />

        </fragment>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment4"
            android:name="fragment4"
            android:label="fragment4"/>     
</navigation>
```

What am I missing? How should I achieve this?

Comment: Your `app:destination` for `action_fragment3_to_fragment4` is `confirmPinFragment`, not `fragment4`. How are you getting to Fragment4?

Comment: @ianhanniballake thank you for pointing out but it was a typo I corrected it